# Hide/Show Nav-Item after success of javascript post

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a nav bar with 4 nav-items and was hoping to hide one of them until i have submited a form and recieved a response. Is this possible?
The form posts to an external API and on success will return a few opptions which i would like to display on the 4 nav-item. I can display the response without a problem but i would prefer not to see the 4th nav-item until the post has been succesful otherwise it will just be blank anyways

HTML

```
                 <ul class="nav nav-stretch nav-line-tabs nav-line-tabs-2x border-transparent fs-5 fw-bolder flex-nowrap"
                    id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active text-active-primary me-6" id="freight-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                           href="#freight" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Freight</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link text-active-primary me-6" id="order-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#order"
                           role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Order Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link text-active-primary me-6" id="customer-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                           href="#customer" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Customer
                            Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item disabled" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link text-active-primary me-6" id="aervices-tab" data-toggle="tab"
                           href="#services" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">>Freight Services</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Javascript

```
        $(document).on('click', 'button[data-wizard-type="action-submit"]', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let wizardData = $("#freight_form").serialize();
        console.log(wizardData);
        $.post({
            url: "{{ route('warehouse.shipping.post_shipping_data') }}",
            data: "order_number={{$order_details->order_number}}&" + wizardData,
            success: function(result){
                const obj = JSON.parse(result);

                console.log(obj.availableFreightServices);
                Swal.fire({
                    position: "top-right",
                    icon: "success",
                    title: "Your work has been saved",
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: A simple `document.getElementById('ID HERE').classList.remove('disabled')` should work, just give your last `li` an ID. There’s other more complicated selectors that you can use, too

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas knew it would be simple lol

Comment: Just initially hide the nav item with `display:none` whenever you receive response you show it with `document.getElementById("element").style.display= '';` I use this very often.

Answer (score 0):

make that nav by default display:none

```
eg. <nav id="navID" style="display:none;"></nav>
and
use on ajax success :
document.getElementById("navID").style.display= 'block';
```